# Characterizations of the sequences $(x_k)$ without convergent subsequences

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying real analysis in higher dimensions and I'm trying to prove the following equivalence:

> $(x_k)$ doesn't have a convergent subsequence $\Leftrightarrow$ for every bounded
>   set $L\subset \mathbb R^n$, the set of the indices $k$ such that
>   $x_k\in L$ is finite.

The ($\Leftarrow$) part is trivial

I need help to prove the ($\Rightarrow$) part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be easier to prove the contrapositive of $\Rightarrow$. (If I'm not mistaken) If there exist a bounded subset $L$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $\{ k \in \mathbb{N}, \, x_{k} \in L \}$ is infinite, then $(x_{k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a convergent subsequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a proof by contradiction. Suppose that you can find a bounded set $L\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that contains infinites $x_k$. Then using to Bolzano-Weirstrass you can find a convergent subsequence in $L$. In this way we have found a contradiction.

Comment: of course, thank you!